# OR operation in WHERE clause

Tags: android

Right now my code looks like this:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(messagesUri, null,"address=?", smsNo, null);
```

where `smsNo` is a singleton array.

I would like to add elements to this array and implement an OR operation in the WHERE clause. Is this possible to do continuing to use an array?

Comment: Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(messagesUri, null,"address   =?"+ "your value" +" or address=?", smsNo, null);

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting user-supplied query values directly in your query string like this; you open yourself up to the possibility of an SQL-injection attack.  It may not be serious in this context, but avoiding such problems is a good habit to get into for when it does matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but you certainly can continue to use an array here. If you're asking how to extend an existing array to have more items, you can use Arrays.copyOf(oldArray, newSize) to make additional space in it.  And you can then just use multiple ? placeholders in your query string to reference the new items.

For example:

```
 queryParameters = Arrays.copyOf(smsNo, 2);
 queryParameters[1] = "another number"

 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(messagesUri, null,"address=? or address=?", queryParameters, null);
```

Comment: I was overcomplicating the situation here, I though that you somehow had to specify the exact positions of the values in queryParameters (something like queryParameters[0] etc.). Anyway, this was what I was looking for, thanks!